# How to prevent windows error 10054 when unplugging network cable

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a c++ application that uses a TCP socket to transfer a file from one processor to another.  The applications will be running on an unreliable network so it is important for the transfers to continue when connectivity is lost and regained.  I am using ACE to allow the application to run on Windows or Linux.

Currently, when I start a transfer and break the network connection between the two processors, if I reconnect it in less than about 20 seconds, the transfer picks back up and everything works fine.  If the connection is not reestablished within 20 seconds, I get Windows error 10054 indicating the connection has been reset.  At that point, the socket is gone and the transfer will not resume once connectivity is reestablished.  Is there a way to override that so that I am in control of when the connection gets timed out?

Edit:  This seems to be a Windows issue.  I tried sending a file from a Linux VM to a Windows box.  I disconnected the network cable for over 5 minutes during the transfer.  When I reconnected it, the transfer picked up right where it left off and completed.

Comment: Use a connection-less protocol then?

Comment: I was actually using UDP originally.  Since I am transfering file data, it was easier to let TCP handle making sure everything gets from one side to the other properly.

Comment: Probably, but that's not really a solution is it? Set it to an hour and then when you get a real failure it's going to sit their crossing it's fingers hoping the problem gets solved. Better off with the failure being detected and then reinitiating the connection and potentially resuming the transfer. Robust comms isn't about closing your eyes tight and hoping everything gets fixed before you have to open them again.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "real failure".  The application does many other things including notifying clients which other systems are offline.  At that point the file transfer would be in a suspended state and the user would be aware of this as well.  The requirement is that as long as both sides remain logged in, the transfer should continue once connectivity is restored.  The bandwidth between systems is very limited so if they are 90% finished transfering a large file, I thought it would make more sense to continue it rather than start over.

Comment: DO NOT UNPLUG THE CABLE?! On a serious notjust use UDP for example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the subject should say *How to handle*, not *How to prevent*, right? You definitely want to get this error, as (per your comment) *at that point the file transfer would be in a suspended state and the user would be aware of this as well*. In order to suspend and inform the user you need to get an error.

Anyhow, the 20 seconds you mentioned is probably due to a timeout in your OS/router. The number can vary significantly and you shouldn't rely on it in any way. You could try to update the timeout on every single box on your path, but that's usually not possible and doesn't really solve you problem (you can always lose connectivity for longer than timeout you have set).

In order to build a solution which is immune to timeouts, you need a simple protocol on top of your raw connection and allow to reconnect and resume transfer from specific offset of your data stream. You could modify your client to send the request with details about retransmission point.

If your network is really unreliable and breaks often, you could switch to UDP. Some packets will arrive, some will be missing. You can collect the blocks and request retransmission for parts of data that haven't arrived. You'll probably need to spend a little bit more time on designing the right protocol, but the solution may be superior to standard TCP.

Comment: The subject is correct, I was hoping to prevent it.  The rest of the messages in the system are sent via UDP and there is a heart beat mechanism used to determine whether or not the other systems are online.  That is what the on/offline status is based on as well as the suspended file transfer status.  I was hoping this was something that could be addressed at the s/w level but if that is not the case, you are correct, we cannot depend on updating every single box in the path.  If that is the case that case, UDP may be the way to go.

Comment: I know the subject is correct, I'm just in a little bit cocky mood, sorry ;-) Well, you can try to mess with the tcp setup on your machines and probably extend this 20s window, but you can get this error for many other reasons (for exampe the remote side crashes). If you develop a solution immune to the timeout, you can handle all the cases. Then you can play with your OS/routers and try to improve transfer rates/reliability, but without affecting the whole image. That's my opinion, but it highly depends on your system.

Comment: @Rob I think your question was slightly misunderstood by people (also by me). You might like to ask the question on serverfault.com indicating you want to extend the timeout on your system and/or what other parameters might be useful to amend to the connection alive during long outage. My impression is stackoverflow sucks when comes to socket/networking questions.

Comment: It's worse than that - the path may change for succesive packets if there is more than one route to host.  Your thousands-of-mileage may vary:)

Answer (score 0):

While there are probably some socket options you could experiment with, the right solution is likely this:

**Build reconnect logic into whatever protocol you have implemented on top of TCP.**

You will always have socket disconnects to deal with, even if you glue the network cable into the port. So you might as well just focus on making your sockets periodically try to "reconnect" and then have your protocol aware of handling this situation.  (e.g try to reconnect every N seconds, possibly waiting longer each time until some max timeout).  And then for the protocol specific changes, I would work off the premise that the receiver should dictate to the sender from what point to start transferring data.  Similar to how a web browser tells an http server how to resume a file transfer.

Comment: "Similar to how a web browser tells an http server how to resume a file transfer."  Or an FTP client telling an FTP server.